# HCW8078 Hybrid Exchange Error

Tags: exchange, exchange-migration, exchange-hybrid

I did a fresh install of DC1 DC2 and Exchange so I'm not sure why I am getting errors still.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/78nab.jpg

Comment: Stop trying to configure the hybrid, unless your plan is to migrate your on premises mailboxes to Office 365, which is not what I think you're trying to do, based on your other question.

Answer (score 0):

In a similar [case](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/msonline/en-US/758bb80a-0f49-4c7a-9c32-9b15b955bf23/hcw-error-8078?forum=onlineservicesexchange), it said that you could check on your internet facing server, whether EWS virtual directory is configured correct.

Get-WebServicesVirtualDirectory -Server InternetFacingServer | fl ExternalUrl,MRSProxyEnabled

Make sure EWS external url could be accessed from external of your organization first. Then you can try to disable MRSProxyEnabled and enable is again, after that run IISReset in CMD with administrator rights.

Wait for IIS restart successfully, then try to run HCW again.